# How many of vs How many

Tags: determiners

I want to know when I should use How many of...  over How many...
I have seen both of them, but don't know how the grammar works behind

e.g.:

How many of them do you know?

How many languages do you speak?

Answer (score 1):

*The real grammatical and syntactical differentiation between your examples is that "many of" is used along with **pronouns(such as them)**, and **determiners( such as the/his/their, etc. ). Besides, there is not too much difference in meaning between them;hence, it really depends upon the context.***

> *Conclusion - Reference:*
>
> ***1) many of + pronoun / determiner + plural countable noun;***
>
> ***2) many of + [personal] pronoun;***

> ***3) many + plural countable noun;***
>
> ***4) many + a + singular countable noun ( a similar meaning to 3), yet more formal );***

***5) the + many + plural countable noun ( a more definite meaning );***

*Nevertheless, "Many" can be used in the comparative structures as well as a pronoun ( recommended for more formal occasions ).*

*e.g.*

> *I did not have **as many opportunities as** you did.*
>
> ***Many** knew she was going to vomit at the party. ( = **'Many of the people present knew ..... '**)*

Answer (score 0):

**Them** is a personal pronoun that you use when you refer back to people/creatures/items that you have already mentioned.

So, in this context your first question would be:

> How many languages do you speak?

And if you followed up, wanting to know more about these languages, you might ask:

> How many **of them** did you learn at school?

**Of them** is another way of saying **of these languages**.

Comment: 'How many' in "How many languages...." is adjectival, whereas, "How many of the languages" has 'How many' like a Pronoun.